# достать одну запись из массива json

Tags: ajax, json

как из массива который выведен циклом в php достать в ajax последнюю запись и вывести?

данные которые выводит php скрипт

```
{"685":"Apple","692":"iPhone 5","700":"iPhone 7"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот таким способом. Но учите что изначальный порядок элементов в объекте может быть не таким как вы ожидаете.

```js
const obj = JSON.parse('{"685":"Apple","692":"iPhone 5","700":"iPhone 7"}'),
result = Object.fromEntries([Object.entries(obj).pop()])
console.log(result);
```

Comment: работает, а если через alert?

Comment: @аноним замените ```console.log(result)``` на ```alert(alert(JSON.stringify(result)))```

Comment: @Plikard если выводите объект строкой (в консоли или alert), то лучше так: `alert(JSON.stringify(result,null,4))`